# Question about reification

Tags: scala, continuations

I am reading a [blog post](http://suereth.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-you-should-think-about-delimited.html) about continuations, which describes how the `reset` block is reified. Can anybody formulate the exact rule of that reification?

Answer (score 1):

The linked paper by Tiark Rompf, Ingo Maier, Martin Odersky contains many examples of Scala's continuations, as well as implementation details of the compiler plugin,

http://lamp.epfl.ch/~rompf/continuations-icfp09.pdf